# Irrlicht -  Using SMesh, SMeshBuffer and SceneManager->AddOctreeSceneNode(...)

Tags: c++, 3d, irrlicht

I need to draw a very large number of 3d lines. If I use `driver->draw3dLine(...)`, the performance drops very badly. I heard that using the Octree we can optimize the drawing by displaying only what we need to see but I'm confused as to how to use it to solve my problem.

Comment: Are those lines supposed to form a surface?

Comment: no they are not forming a surface they are just lines pointing from one object to another

Comment: AFAICT the octree stuff Irrlicht makes available on hand deals with 2D meshes, so I'm not sure how realistic it is to turn your lines into a mesh.

Comment: i have to agree with u, but do u have any other way that i can draw many lines without dropping the frame rate below 30

Comment: Just guessing, but deal with the scene manager, not the video driver. The former is especially designed to deal with culling and the like.